# Unable to update Samsung S3

Tags: updates, email, exchange, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I am new to this community.
I bought a new S3 android phone. Well, I gotta configure couple of my email accounts.
1. personal - gmail, 2. official - exchange mail.

When I look for update, it says that device is encrypted and unable to update.

1. Do I need to decrypt to update every time?
2. Is there a way to convert my PIN screen-lock to pattern screen-lock without deleting my existing credentials?

Looking forward a simple solution, thanks!